# ggplot animate time series, time series shoul be revealed over seconds

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to make a ggplot time series, but i want the time series to be revealed over several seconds and date or xlab should show in minutes.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=`Date-TimeStamp`, y=DO, group= Batch))+
geom_line(aes(color= Batch))+
scale_color_manual(values=c('#7e7be4','#f33b8d','#269cad'))+
scale_x_time(breaks = "1 Minute" , labels = "%M %S")+
ggtitle("Time Series Plot of DO)" )+ 
labs(x="Date", y="DO")
```

[image]

NOTE: I'll also like to animate it

Comment: Each question should be self-sufficient, please dont link to additional code but provide it here.

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you, I have edited the question appropriately.